# Two lines of code mashing together but I need them separately

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Safeties;
        out.print("Safeties:");
        Safeties = input.nextInt();
        out.print("Home Team:");
        String HomeTeam = input.nextLine();
        out.print("Touchdowns:");
        double Touchdown2 = input.nextDouble();
        }
}
```

The output is:
Safties:
Home Team:Touchdowns:

But it's supposed to be
Safties:
Home Team:
Touchdowns:

I'm assuming it's because I have an int above a string but I don't know how to fix this problem. I need them in that order. I'm completely lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: Dude, what, what, where and what?

Answer (score 0):

Add `input.nextLine();` below `out.print("Home Team:");`